# Indices error while converting dict to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have to make this JSON Object:

```
cookie = {"SX": '{"gc":1,"gsc":1,"ls":[{"itn":"20456","qty":1,"ritn":"20456","tp":0}]}'}
```

For that purpose I am using a dictionary and a list like so

```
cookieJson = {} 
sku = '20456'
d = {'itn':sku,'qty':1,'ritn':sku,'tp':0}
l.append(d)
cookieJson["SX"] = {'gc':1,'gsc':1,'ls':l}
j = json.dumps(cookieJson)
cookie = j #Error here
html = session.get('https://example.com',headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=5, cookies=cookie)
```

However it is throwing an exception: `string indices must be integers not str dictionary`

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT** by LukasGraf:

This is what a complete example should look like:

```
import json

sku = 5
l = []
cookieJson = {}

d = {'itn':sku,'qty':1,'ritn':sku,'tp':0}
l.append(d)
cookieJson["SX"] = {'gc':1,'gsc':1,'ls':l}
j = json.dumps(cookieJson)
print j
```

- It contains *everything* needed to run it. All imports are included, all names used in the example are defined
- *Anyone* can copy and paste this into a `*.py` file and run it without changing a single character
- This example works, as you can test for yourself. So please update it accordingly so it exhibits the problem you're having.

Comment: Where are sku, l, and cookieJson defined? Is this your actual indentation? What line does the error occur on?

Comment: It looks like `cookieJson` is a string, and you expect it to be a dictionary. But since it's not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Kevin and Lukas Graf Question updated

Comment: @Volatil3 it's still not complete. `cookieJson` is not being defined in your example.

Comment: Always copy-paste the **full** traceback message you get from Python. It makes finding the problem so much easier.

Comment: @LukasGraf left in copy-pasting.

Comment: @Evert I am not getting any Traceback at all. Only string message I mentioned above

Comment: `session` is a string..?

Comment: @JRicardo000 session is a `requests.Session()` object

Comment: @Volatil3 it still is not complete. I'll edit your question to give you an example what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) looks like.

Comment: Does the error still occur if you remove the `html = session.get` line? I don't want to query random websites if this is just a json problem.

Comment: why don't you just use a cookiejar?

Comment: @Kevin it's definitely a problem in the `.get()`

Comment: @Kevin Yes just rechecked, it is due to `session.get()`

Comment: @zmo how `cookiejar` going to solve issue?

Comment: @zmo actually I just want to parameterised this: `cookie = {"SHCT": '{"gc":1,"gsc":1,"ls":[{"itn":"xxx","qty":1,"ritn":"xxx","tp":0}]}'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here I'm trying your example:

```
>>> import json, requests
>>> l = []
>>> 
>>> cookieJson = {} 
>>> sku = '20456'
>>> d = {'itn':sku,'qty':1,'ritn':sku,'tp':0}
>>> l.append(d)
>>> cookieJson["SX"] = {'gc':1,'gsc':1,'ls':l}
>>> j = json.dumps(cookieJson)
>>> html = requests.get('https://example.com', cookies=cookieJson)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

your problem is that your trying to use anything but strings as values of the cookie
dictionary, whereas a cookie dictionary shall be a simple flat dictionary using only
strings. So the following works fine:

```
>>> d = {'itn':sku,'qty':'1','ritn':sku,'tp':'0'}
>>> html = requests.get('https://example.com', cookies=d)
```

your problem is that you're using the integer datatype, whereas cookies only work with
strings. You can't have `1`s or `0`s, as well as you can't have a dict as value.

If you really insist on creating a cookie with multiple values, your only solution would be to do the following:

```
>>> html = requests.get('https://example.com', cookies={"mycookie": json.dumps(cookieJson)})
```

where you create your cookie, that contains a full json string as value, under the `"mycookie"` key. Then only, you'll deserialize the value of the cookie to get your data back.

Comment: The website creates cookie in this form: ` {"SX": '{"gc":1,"gsc":1,"ls":[{"itn":"xxx","qty":1,"ritn":"xxx","tp":0}]}'}` Should I replace `mycookie` with `SX` ?

Comment: indeed, and as you're showing off, they're actually embedding the json data inside a full string!

Comment: Yes Sir! it worked now. Though I don't get why setting `cookieJson["SX"] ` will not work?